# Formulario Rectaivo en Angular 5: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid'

Tags: angular4

El mensaje completo que obtengo al cargar el componente (en la inicialización del mismo) es:

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of null at ProbaComponent.verificaValidTouched**

En el componente defino el formulario así:

```js
formulario: FormGroup;
   
.....
   
this.formulario = this.formBuilder.group({
    averia : this.formBuilder.group({
  CODIGO: ['0],
  DESCRIP: ['', Validators.required],
  ESTADO: [0, Validators.required],
  TIPO: [0, Validators.required],
      }),
      informador : this.formBuilder.group({
  INF_NOME: ['', Validators.required],
  INF_TLNO: ['', Validators.required],
  INF_EMAIL: ['']
      }),
});
```

el html:

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label for="INF_NOME" class="form-control-label">
      Teléfono para contacto</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"
  [ngClass]="aplicaCssErro('INF_NOME')"
  id="INF_NOME"  formControlName="INF_NOME" autofocus>
</div>
```

Y la función a la que llama el html:

```js
verificaValidTouched(campo) {
 return !this.formulario.get(campo).valid && this.formulario.get(campo).touched;
}
  
aplicaCssErro(campo) {
   if (this.formulario && this.verificaValidTouched(campo)) {
     return 'is-invalid';
   } else {
     return '';
   }
}
```

Si hago traza de la ejecución, la función aplicaCssErro(campo) se ejecuta despues de crearse el formulario.

No acabo de entender en donde me estoy equivicando.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un formulario que anida a otros dos formularios. Cuando creas formularios compuestos de otros formularios, los campos no se añaden simplemente al formulario padre, necesitas recorrer el árbol para llegar a ellos:

```
verificaValidTouched(form, campo) {
 return !this.formulario.get(form).get(campo).valid && this.formulario.get(form).get(campo).touched;
}

aplicaCssErro(form, campo) {
   if (this.formulario && this.formulario.get(form) && this.verificaValidTouched(form,campo)) {
     return 'is-invalid';
   } else {
     return '';
   }
}
```

con lo que tu HTML quedaría:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"
 [ngClass]="aplicaCssErro('informador','INF_NOME')"
 id="INF_NOME"  formControlName="INF_NOME" autofocus>
```

Comment: Horas, horas, horas .... Muchas gracias Pablo Lozano, tu ciencia ilumina mi día!!!